# Matrix Centre Alignment of Bottom Row

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to get the centred transpose of 1 in a multi column matrix. Any suggesstions?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried?

Comment: using bmatrix, and inputting the values, but the bottom value is shifted towards the left.

Comment: You should add your code to the question (and to your future question). Btw, you have got 2 answers here, if one of them helps you, accept it, or tell the answerer what you really want by commenting under their post otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Nest a `matrix` inside the `bmatrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\matr{Z}_0=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{matrix}
  \matr{A} & \matr{B} \\
  \matr{X}_{tr} & \matr{X}_{tst} \\
  \end{matrix}
\\
\matr{1}^T
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

an alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{Z}_0=
    \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \\
\mathbf{X}_{tr} & \mathbf{X}_{tst} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\mathbf{1}^T}
    \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]